# Many foreign keys in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a books database in Postgres, and I want to add an authorId column, but I don't know how to make it work when a book has many authors.

Author table

```
authorId    firstName    lastName
1           Terry        Pratchett
2           Neil         Gaiman
```

Book table

```
bookId    name             authorId
1         Good Omens       1, 2
```

How do I make it work? My first idea was storing authorId as an array.

My desired query would look something like this

```
SELECT firstName, lastName 
FROM author 
WHERE authorId IN 
    (SELECT authorId 
     FROM book 
     WHERE bookId=1);
```

and it would return this

```
firstName    lastName
Terry        Pratchett
Neil         Gaiman
```

But I have a feeling that it won't work, and there is a better way to do it.

Comment: That's a horrible idea. You should learn about normalization

Comment: I don't think it's a horrible idea, normalization is not always the best choice in practice (adds redundancy, more tables to manage, more joins, poor performance, ...), and this is why Postgres has array a data type which is widely used in industry

Comment: @pedram bashiri: You are wrong. Normalization never adds redundancy, as the main purpose of normalization is to *reduce* redundancy. And It also adds consistency (in this example it guarantees that you only link books to existing author IDs). And last but not least: it adds speed. Finding the authors of a book with a bridge table is usually extremely fast (appropriate indexes provided), while the array approach tends to be extremely slow, because the only way to find a book ID in the table is to read all records.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You mean you disagree that using a mapping(bridge) table here adds redundancy comparing to using an array?!! regarding performance I agree that _in this case_ depending on the size of authors table mapping table could be faster. But my point is, it's not like normalization is always _the solution_, maybe it is in text books but not in industry.

Comment: @pedram bashiri: As to redundancy: Yes. I don't see where a bridge table adds any redundancy. It doesn't. As to normalization: A database should be normalized. An array doesn't necessarily violate normalization, however. When you store something as a string, you should not be interested in its substrings in your DBMS (then you should rather store the substrings separately). Same for an array: when you store an array, you should not be interested in single elements of that array...

Comment: @pedram bashiri: ... In this example we are very much interested in the single array elemants, as they are even IDs. It is not a good idea to store IDs in an array, as this can lead to inconsistencies. If you want to store, say, memo notes or the like, an array can come very handy, though. As to the industry: I've worked for more than 25 years with rather big databases (more than thousand tables) and I've seen normalization violated here and there. That usually comes at a price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook solution would be to have an additional "mapping" table to map books and authors. This way an author may author several books, and a book may have several authors:

```
CREATE TABLE book_authors (
    author_id INT NOT NULL,
    book_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY book_authors_pk (author_id, book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY author_fk (author_id) REFERENCES authors (author_id),
    FOREIGN KEY book_fk (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id)
)
```

Then you can use a `join` to query the authors of a book:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM   authors a
JOIN   book_authors ba on a.author_id = ba.author_id
WHERE  book_id = 1
```

Or if you don't have the book's id, another join with `books` will allow you to query its details:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM   authors a
JOIN   book_authors ba ON a.author_id = ba.author_id
JOIN   books b ON ba.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE  b.name = 'Good Omens'
```

Answer (score 0):

m:n relations (one author can write many books + one book can be written by many authors) are best modelled with a bridge table:

- author (author_id, first_name, last_name)
- book (book_id, title)
- book_author (book_id, author_id)

The query to get the authors of book #1:

```
select first_name, last_name
from author
where author_id in (select author_id from book_author where book_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the fact that you're using postgres gives you the great option of storing authorIds as an array. You can define your table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
 bookId serial not null,
 name varchar,
 authorIds int[]
);
```

And your select query should be

```
SELECT firstName, lastName 
FROM author 
WHERE authorId IN 
 (SELECT unnest(authorIds) 
  FROM Book 
  WHERE bookId = 1);
```